# tf.keras.metrics.Metric weight with concatenation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am wondering if there is a way to use concatenation in the weight of a metric, something like:

```
class A(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

  def __init__(self, name='a', **kwargs):
    super(A, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.stack = self.add_weight(name='stack', initializer='[]')

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    self.stack.assign_concat(tf.reduce_sum(y_true))  # Simple reduce sum example, may be other f()
```

the idea is to keep track of all the values seen and use them on the `result` function with the benefit of `reset_states` clearing the weight.